# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ? Error in Async module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

```
function(callback){
                Club.aggregate({
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$positioninclub"
                    }
                }, (err, newResult) => {
                   callback(err, newResult) ;
                });
            },
```

My code have problem in this portion... i am trying to add this code in parallel method of async module.

```
router.get('/',ensureAuthentication,function(req,res){
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        //find function return the array
        Club.find({},(err,result) => {
            callback(err,result);
        });
    },
    function(callback){
                Club.aggregate({
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$positioninclub"
                    }
                }, (err, newResult) => {
                   callback(err, newResult) ;
                });
            },
],(err,results) => {
    const resl = results[0];
    const resl1 = results[1];

    console.log(resl);
    const dataChunk = [];
    const chunkSize = 3;

    for(let i = 0;i < resl.length ; i = i + chunkSize){
        dataChunk.push(resl.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
    }
    console.log(dataChunk);
    res.render('dashboard', {title: 'Portal', resl: resl});
})
```

Comment: Something's very wrong here. Is this actually mongoose? If so then `Model.find()` should always return an array even where there are no results. If there's no `length` property then something different is being returned. If it's not mongoose and just the base driver, then these methods don't actually return arrays and that would explain it. So which driver are you using actually?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct aggregate formate :

```
 Model.aggregate([{}]) instead of Model.aggregate({})
```

Use Like:

```
Club.aggregate([{
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$positioninclub"
                    }
                }], (err, newResult) => {
                   callback(err, newResult) ;
                });
```